# How to know a redis command is write or readonly?

Tags: redis, jedis

I mean is there a command used to check whether a redis command is readonly?

```
is_readonly(command)
```

It will better if there is command in Jedis.

Answer (score 3):

with `COMMAND` you can get list of all commands with command flags such as
`readonly`

so here's the list I've end up with:

`publish bgsave sunion readonly exists hstrlen lindex scan ping latency ttl wait zscore zrevrangebylex sscan geohash getbit hkeys zrange monitor llen save auth zcard shutdown sync dbsize subscribe zrangebylex zlexcount mget getrange bitpos config lrange replconf discard asking client pfselftest bgrewriteaof unsubscribe zrank readwrite hget bitcount randomkey time zrevrank sinter dump strlen unwatch smembers georadius lastsave slowlog sismember hexists multi sdiff geopos hscan script keys hvals pfcount zscan echo command select zcount substr pttl hlen info scard geodist srandmember hgetall cluster psync pubsub psubscribe zrevrange hmget object watch zrangebyscore get type zrevrangebyscore punsubscribe georadiusbymember`

though you might want to exclude readonly admin commands - they don't change data but can cause side effects. here's list with excluded admin:

`publish sunion readonly exists hstrlen lindex scan ping ttl wait zscore zrevrangebylex sscan geohash getbit hkeys zrange llen auth zcard dbsize subscribe zrangebylex zlexcount mget getrange bitpos lrange discard asking client pfselftest unsubscribe zrank readwrite hget bitcount randomkey time zrevrank sinter dump strlen unwatch smembers georadius lastsave slowlog sismember hexists multi sdiff geopos hscan script keys hvals pfcount zscan echo command select zcount substr pttl hlen info scard geodist srandmember hgetall pubsub psubscribe zrevrange hmget object watch zrangebyscore get type zrevrangebyscore punsubscribe georadiusbymember`

more here: http://redis.io/commands/command#examples

I think you might also check which commands is available for specific redis server version.